# Approach to learning algorithms using a specific language

Tags: java, algorithm

So for the summer I decided that I may as well start learning algorithms before school starts. I've been told that the class is fairly fast paced, and that algorithms isn't something you should take lightly (I have a tendency to do this with all the course work during the semester lol).

The book we're going to use is this [Algorithms (4th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032157351X).
Anyway, this is my problem.

I'm almost third way through the book, but I just realized what I was doing. For example, I would read and re-read the sections I don't quite understand. Then if I feel confident enough, I would try to reproduce the same algorithm in java from my head. But by doing this, my code looks almost exactly like the ones in the book..in java.

I can't say I'm just memorizing code after code--I do understand the concepts and they help me code these algorithms--but I feel like I'll only be able to implement these algorithms in java. I should note that I only know java at the moment.

tldr: I'm learning algorithms as if I'm learning to play the guitar--repetition after repetition. But by doing so I feel like I'm being more fixated that I'll only able to implement these in java. How exactly would you learn algorithms if the book you're using is language-specific?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd write them in whatever language the book uses. Then I might write them in something else. Or vice-versa.

Comment: Unless you plan on writing some Haskell or Perl in the near future, I wouldn't worry. Most programming languages aren't that different, and most share a basic universal feature set (although syntax and world-view tend to change.) Once you have experience you'll be able to pick up new languages like lint. Right now focus on the actual concepts in the algorithms rather than what language you use to write them.

Comment: It isn't available until June 25th, but you may find [this Udacity course on algorithms](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs215) to prove useful.

Comment: One thing to think about is complexity, try to understand it to be able to analyze the differences

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Don't Confuse Yourself

**You're studying Java, so write them in Java.** Especially if Java is your first language. Don't confuse yourself for now, as you are trying to learn 2 things at once: *how to progam in Java*, and *how to progam*. **You're learning both a new language and a way of thinking.** Don't do too much but adding another language to the sauce for now.

## Diversify

Later on, or if you feel confident enough that you can take on another language simultaneously, then it would obviously be beneficial to learn another one and try to replicate the algorithms without looking at the book.

## Reproduce and Extend

What we could recommend you is to look for derivates of the algorithms. Known variants, that have been documented, and where you could just read the description of the variant so you can try to implement it from the "base" version, without needing to read the book.

For instance, if your book introduced you to a linked list, you should be able to come up with the algorithm for a doubly-linked list or a circular linked list without reading more than a description of the desired outcome. Or there's something about the original concepts that you clearly misunderstood.

## Try First, Read-On Later

I'd recommend you actually even **try to implement the algorithms described in your book before they show them to you**. The point of seeing Sedgewick's algorithm is to see a canonical implementation, which is considered a standard blueprint. If you just read the section leading up to the implementation (which hopefully is displayed first), then just sit down with the book, and try to figure out how you could do that. If you can't do that at all, then you're too far ahead in your book and should backtrack and start again from scratch.

Comment: Thanks, I really like the idea of trying to implement before looking at the example in the book.

Comment: @user1164937: when I studied, we basically were never shown an implementation, we were just coding away all the time and when blocked we would ask assistants (Which would 99% of the time come, read our code, laugh, ask what was wrong or what we didn't understand, and end up telling us "RTFM". And though that's harsh, that's a pretty good approach.) The only time we saw an implementation was when we would have a group lecture and they would project their editor on-screen while typing the program live. Taking notes was not forbidden, but advised not to. Books were frowned upon during at first.

Comment: @user1164937: and you're welcome, I'm glad if it helps you. Drop us a note later if you got where you wanted based on that :)

Answer (score 2):

Thing about algorithms, they're essentially language-agnostic.  There's really nothing stopping you from doing Sedgewick's examples in C, Python or some other language.

If you really don't know any other languages, concentrate on Java.  Sure, its a bit repetitious, but those bits will stick in your head in a good way and come test time, you'll be glad for the information.

You're in an interesting position right now, since the kind of thinking required to write programs is very different from normal thinking. Add to that the fact you're learning a whole new language with a different syntax, punctuation and the like.  Practice really does make perfect, since there are many bits and pieces to remember.

Oh, if you want practice with algorithms, try out [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/index.php), [code kata](http://codekata.pragprog.com/) and other challenge sites.  These little challenges can help you familiarize yourself with the language as well as get comfortable with the type of thinking required.

Answer (score 1):

First, congrats on taking your first steps on learning how to code. I would say that you are already ahead of your peers by starting to look ahead during the summer.

As far as your fears on only being able to implement algorithms in Java, you have already demonstrated that it will not be a problem for you. It sounds like you are passionate enough to get started early so you should have no problem implementing a solution in multiple languages. Additionally most of the languages with C/C++ (Java and C# to name a few) like syntax will be similar enough that you will be able to translate your knowledge seamlessly.

The best advice that I can give is to CODE, CODE, CODE!! Don't just read about the algorithms actually implement them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say how well you know the mathematics behind the algorithms.  That will be key in determining your facility with the code.

Sedgewick's books are very good.  I'd feel free to pick some and check out other books as well, like "Numerical Recipes" and "Numerical Methods That Work".  See if another point of view can clarify for you.

If you don't feel like you're getting enough out of copying Java, see if you can translate them into another language, maybe Python or purely functional alternative.  If you can do that, you'll know you've got it.

Answer (score 0):

I would either try to learn another language to verify that you can actually port it to another language (javascript would be my vote because it is simple and useful on the front and backend) or write the algorithms out in pseudocode since that is more language agnostic. Most languages will have the code look pretty similar. The only thing to be very careful about is when you are relying on some aspect of the language (such as generics or iterators in java) which you may not be able to use in another language and that could leave a gap in your understanding.

Another way to verify that you actually understand the algorithm is to make slight changes in the problem and make sure that you can adjust the algorithm to still work.  For example if it is a sorting algorithm then try to sort by several different attributes rather than just one, if it is a graph algorithm make the graph a digraph and see how things should change.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm learning algorithms as if I'm learning to play the
>   guitar--repetition after repetition.

Then you are not learning algorithms. You are learning repetition. Two different things. The usage of a programming language by an algorithms book is a secondary factor. It is just a vehicle of instruction, an implementation detail.

What you should be focusing is on understanding the structure, logic and mathematical characteristics of an algorithm (and possibly the data structure(s) associated with it.)

That's what your focus should be.

> But by doing so I feel like I'm being more fixated that I'll only able
>   to implement these in java.

But that is because you are focusing on just how the algorithm is being coded (in Java in this particular case.) You are focusing on an implementation detail.

When you learn to drive, you don't focus on how you learn to drive a Honda Civic or a Nissan Maxima. You learn the essence of what driving is, the rules of thumbs, the necessary precautions and the laws governing driving a vehicle.

Same with learning algorithms. You don't learn "Algorithms in Java" no more than "Algorithms in Haskell". You learn Algorithms first and foremost, the vehicle (sans very specialized cases) is secondary.

You should be focusing on *what* the algorithm does, *how* and *why*. Questions like *"how/why does it work?"* and most importantly *"what are the performance characteristics?", those are the things you should be focusing on.

Every good algorithms book (Sedgewick's included) carry that message. That's what you should focus on. How you get to that re-focusing, that's a function of one's personal learning strategies.

> How exactly would you learn algorithms if the book you're using is language-specific?

By not focusing on the language. Focus on the structure, focus on the data structures involved, the invariants, pre-conditions and post-conditions. Understand asymptotic behavior described in Big-O (or Big-Omicron), Little-O/Little-Omicron and Omega notations.

You are learning algorithms, not programming in Java via coding algorithms.

If you can't do this mental leap, it means you do not have sufficient practice or abstract analysis. It is not an insult, but an observation and an advice. Coding, the usage of a programming language is typically secondary to the mathematical analysis of computing, the focus of Computer Science (of which Algorithms is a part thereof.)

**NOTE** I've done Java for over 10 years, and though I like it *for work*, I strongly believe it is a poor tool for learning programming or CS topics.

One is better served by learning Algorithms with either A) a procedural, systems-level programming language like C or Ada, or a high-level pseudo-assembler simulator, or B) a functional language like Lisp or Haskell.

Object-Oriented features in pure/pseudo-pure OO languages simply get in the way.

Algorithms are mathematical structures with a nature descriptive of the how (operationally) and/or the what (mathematically). The former is perfectly suited for procedural programming, the later for functional programming.

Comment: I guess the analogy was poor on my part, but what I meant was that I try to grasp the concepts. Re-read if I have to (I've re-read some sections so many times until it clicked). As well as "testing my knowledge" which I do by implementing it in java, since java's the only language I know. Even if I end up implementing it correctly the first time, I do it again because I really want to make it a long term thing.

Comment: Also, I'm interest in Haskell. Very much so when I was thinking about a second language. I have a notion that a functional language wouldn't hurt since I've heard it's a totally different ball park, so I wouldn't be confused with java (I only have a semester's worth of experience). What do you think?

Comment: "What do you think?" -- focus. IMO, if you only know one language (Java), I think you are doing a diservice to yourself learning algorithms by yourself without having a diversified exposure to other languages. Barring the naturally gifted, learning algorithms (but really, really, really learning them) requires the student to have a certain amount of programming practice (ideally in several languages). You should be able to write programs of semi-decent complexity in, say, Java, C, and Python (for example) before engaging in learning algorithms. IMO, it's like learning Calculus without Algebra.